# How to set image in notification in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native

In Android, Native application you can easily set image in notification.
[image]

I need to create this functionality in my application.
I am using https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm 
I think, I have to create new activity for that which override notification builder. but i am confuse where can i override java class using Javascript.
This tutorial help me to understand how to implement image notification in native app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for image you can use `picture` in `custom_notification` using `react-native-fcm` package. It should looks like:

```
      const payload = {
      data: {
          snapshot: JSON.stringify(original),
          custom_notification: JSON.stringify(
{
   id: 'topics/my-notif
   title: `title`,
   body: '',
   sound: 'default',
   priority: 'high',
   icon: 'ic_launcher',
   show_in_foreground: true,
   vibrate: 300,
   action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
   picture: 'https://asfsgsgafasfaf',
}
          )
      }
      //,notification:{title: `Car(${original.name}) registrated`,body: 'Waiting administration approve. ' + original.description}
  };
```

But it is one small issue if you using Firebase storage. Package overrides firebase link. From `%2F` to `/`. SO its a bug, I opened issue here: `https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/931` and maybe it should be merged. So when you put your image from firebase storage it cannot get it and shows blank image...